# ProtoBuf Js in thunderbird extension

Tags: protocol-buffers, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Hi I want to parse a mail in a thunderbird extension and then use protobuf to send some component to a server. My question is how to include the protobuf api and use it with my extension, how to do something like : "script src="ProtoBuf.min.js">/script ".